# Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la intención de listar el nombre de cada producto el cual tiene un precio mayor o igual que la media de todos los productos por cada fabricante.

Traté de solucionarlo con el siguiente query:

```
SELECT pro.nombre
FROM producto AS pro
WHERE pro.precio >= (
    SELECT AVG(pro.precio)
    FROM fabricante AS fa
    INNER JOIN producto AS pro
    ON fa.id = pro.id_fabricante
    GROUP BY fa.nombre
    );
```

El sub query debe encontrar el promedio de los productos por cada fabricante, después se compara con el precio de cada producto. Sin embargo, al momento de ejecutarlo devuelve:

`Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

Comment: ¿Será acaso que tienes el mismo nombre de fabricante con id distintos? Agrega a tu pregunta el resultado de `SHOW CREATE TABLE fabricante`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en el inner join, lo estas añadiendo en la subquery cuando realmente lo necesitas en la query principal para iterar y en la subquery unicamente debes filtrar por los ids de fabricante.

```
SELECT pro.nombre
FROM producto AS pro
INNER JOIN fabricante AS fa
ON fa.id = pro.id_fabricante
WHERE pro.precio >= (
    SELECT AVG(pro2.precio)
    FROM producto AS pro2
    where fa.id = pro2.id_fabricante
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que sería más fácil y no sé si más rápido así:

```
SELECT pro.nombre
  FROM producto        AS pro
 INNER JOIN fabricante AS fa   ON pro.id_fabricante = fa.id
 INNER JOIN producto   AS pro2 ON fa.id = pro2.id_fabricante
 WHERE pro.precio >= AVG(pro2.precio) ;
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona esta consulta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.